# Order of execution in Abstract Class

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

I came across a posting where it is said that MustBeCalled() method will get called if we have the Abstract class do the calling in this manner.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public void PerformThisFunction()
    {
        MustBeCalled();
        AbstractMethod();
    }

    public void MustBeCalled()
    {
        //this must be called when AbstractMethod is invoked
    }

    //could also be public if desired
    protected abstract void AbstractMethod();
}

public class ImplementClass : AbstractClass
{
    protected override void AbstractMethod()
    {
        //when called, base.MustBeCalled() must be called.
        //how can i enforce this?
    }
}
```

But how does MustBeCalled() method get called? 
In what order things are called here?

Comment: There is more than one programming language, you realise? Please tag your questions with the one you are using.

Comment: Why are you wanting to enforce that the sub class of your abstract class must call `MustBeCalled()`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Apologies, It is C#

Comment: @FeistyMango I wanted to understand order of execution in general, this is an example. What is the default order of execution and how can i manipulate it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "default order of execution". Nothing forces you from forgetting to invoke a certain method, and no compiler will do that for you. Simply make the `MustBeCalled` protected and force your callers to use the one and only public method (`PerformThisFunction`) which will call the protected methods in succession.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `PerformFunction()` first, then everything will execute in the intended order, where that order is specified in the order of the lines of code in `PerformFunction()`. If you call `AbstractMethod()` directly, there's no guarantee that `MustBeCalled()` will ever be called. However, I notice that you have `AbstractMethod()` marked as `protected`, which means that outside consumers of your class will not be able to call it directly. They'll have to use `PerformFunction()` -- this is good, as there is now only one public way to invoke your internal methods, and that way guarantees the order that you need.

In truth, there is a level at which you can only guarantee that things happen by choosing to write code to make them happen. You can't, for example, guarantee that code is going to implement a game of Tetris except by actually writing that code and choosing to implement it in such a way that it produces Tetris behavior. The type system and the public/protected/private modifiers can help some by preventing some misuse (as your internals are not accessible and thus cannot be invoked by consumers of your module), but they can only go so far. This is such a case.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enforce how an implementation to call a method when invoked.  The implementation could do its own thing entirely, or do nothing.

```
public class ImplementClass : AbstractClass
{
    protected override void AbstractMethod()
    {
        // this is a perfectly valid implementation
    }
}
```

A better implementation could be.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public void PerformThisFunction()
    {
        MustBeCalled();
        AbstractMethod();
    }

    private void MustBeCalled()
    {

    }

    protected virtual void AbstractMethod()
    {
        MustBeCalled();
    }
}
```

This way refactoring tools will at least create the desired boilerplate code:

```
public class ImplementClass : AbstractClass
{
    protected override void AbstractMethod()
    {
        base.AbstractMethod();
    }
}
```

However, the person overriding `AbstractMethod` still needs to call `base.AbstractMethod`, this is not enforced by the compiler at all.

Comment: if we are already calling MustBeCalled() in AbstractMethod() why do we need PerformThisFunction()?

Comment: I would just add some remarks explaining that there is no "order of execution" concerning `MustBeCalled()`. I get the sense that the OP believes there is some magic that is executing `MustBeCalled()` inside the `AbstractMethod()`. Which there simply isn't.

Comment: @user793468 Great question, the answer is that there is no need for PerformThisFunction() at least in the current context of the example you provided.

Comment: @FeistyMango Thank you. So in my original question. There is no way MustBeCalled() is executed as PerformThisFunction() is never called?

Comment: @user793468 Precisely.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution if you are consuming this ImplementClass externally, unless it is acceptable to call MustBeCalled() multiple times in 1 execution. Imagine a DoWork class that creates an instance of the ImplementClass. It then calls the PerformThisFunction() of the instance. The MustBeCalled() method will be run twice.